# Unable to access OBJECT REPOSITORY from UFT located in HP ALM in subfolders

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

I am working on automation project using UFT . I have uploaded all my function and object repository into HP ALM resource tab. Problem is we are not able to access it from UFT if we place function or object repository under subfolder. See following code.
Following code not working

```
Dim RepPath : RepPath="[ALM\Resources] Resources\Automation\Framework\XYZ\OBJECTREPOSITORY\AUT\File\File.tsr"
RepositoriesCollection.Add(RepPath)
```

And following code is working

```
 Dim RepPath : RepPath="[ALM\Resources] Resources\Automation\File.tsr"
RepositoriesCollection.Add(RepPath)
```

in both the code only difference is subfolder . Please reply if anyone face same problem and how to resolve it .

Comment: What is the error you are getting on trying to add the repo?

Comment: I just tried exactly what you listed (with different folder names), and it worked(UFT 11.53; ALM 11.00).  So, are you certain that your folder names are correct?  Is there a specific reason you need to add a repository at runtime?

Comment: Yes its working now , Error with ALM. Could you please tell me how do i get path of test plan from ALM